# Three.js Shadow doesn't cast on a part of the scene

Tags: three.js

I am having this scene where I cast shadow with a sphere on my plan, all good in the first picture.

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyPEp.png)

When I put the sphere in another place, the shadow is not fully casted on the plan, like in this picture.

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnWHG.png)

This is the code:

```
//Create a DirectionalLight and turn on shadows for the light
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.7, 1 );
light.position.set( 1, 1,1);            
light.castShadow = true;            
light.shadowDarkness = 0.8;
scene.add( light );

//Set up shadow properties for the light
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;  
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.0;   
light.shadow.camera.far = 5;     


var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 32, 32 );
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
sphere.translateY(1);
sphere.translateZ(-5);
sphere.translateX(-2);
sphere.castShadow = true; 
sphere.receiveShadow = false;
scene.add( sphere );
```

Here I receive the shadow on my plan:

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("stone/rush_tex01.json", function ( object ) {    
    object.traverse( function( node ) { if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { node.receiveShadow = true; } } );
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

So what should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase the frustum of the directional light's shadow camera. The code could look like this:

```
var d = 5;
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 20;
```

The following example shows the entire code. You might have to adjust the value of `d` so it works for your specific use case.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webaudio_timing